# Как сделать чтобы каждое действие пользователя приходило к тебе на твой аккаунт

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Сразу уточняю, то что язык программирования python, и библиотека вроде бы telebot или pyTelegramApi. И интересно есть ли решение на данную задачку, если есть будьте добры помочь

Тут объясню по конкретнее, допустим есть пользователь, она нажимает на кнопку и мне надо чтобы на аккаунт мой приходили его все действия которые он будет делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу сказать как сделать логи,
Вот функция логов:

```
def log(message):
    print("<!------!>")
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.now())
    print("Сообщение от {0} {1} (id = {2}) \n {3}".format(message.from_user.first_name,
                                                              message.from_user.last_name,
                                                              str(message.from_user.id), message.text))
```

Вот пример вызова функции(на эхо боте):

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


def lalala(message):
    log(message) #Вот сама функция логов
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    bot.send_message((message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name, str(message.from_user.id), message.text))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

И вот что оно вам примерно пишет:

```
<!------!>
2020-03-24 22:45:36.516786
Сообщение от Иван Иванов None (id = 99999999) 
 /start
<!------!>
2020-03-24 22:45:55.408640
Сообщение от Иван Иванов None (id = 99999999) 
 привет
```